# Error in computed Field of select Query

Tags: mysql, sql

This Query is giving me an error of #1054 - Unknown column 'totalamount' in 'where clause'

```
 SELECT (amount1 + amount2) as totalamount 
 FROM `Donation` 
 WHERE totalamount > 1000
```

I know i can resolve this error by using group by clause and replace my where condition with having clause. But is there any other solution beside using having clause. If group by is the only solution then I want to know why I have to use group by clause even I havent use any aggregate function

thanks.

Comment: Repeat the sum in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: If i have very complex calculations then ?? This is just for example

Comment: Then I guess you're better off with group by and having...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not expect MySQL to give that error message, but many other databases do.  In other databases you can work around it by repeating the column definition:

```
SELECT  amount1 + amount2 as totalamount 
FROM    Donation
WHERE   amount1 + amount2 > 1000
```

Or you can use a subquery to avoid the repitition:

```
SELECT  totalamount 
FROM    (
        select  amount1 + amount2 as totalamount
        ,       *
        from    Donation
        ) as SubQueryAlias
WHERE   totalamount  > 1000
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce40c/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

No way.

**WHERE** filters column while **HAVING** filters on aggregates.

See [SQL Having](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

Comment: Well I said I know how to resolve it by using having clause. I want to know why I have to use group by clause even I havent use any aggregate function

Comment: `create view Tot AS SELECT (amount1 + amount2) AS totalamount from Donation; select * from Tot where totalamount > 1000;`

Comment: A having clause can filter on columns as well as aggregates, [example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79cac/1/0).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the SQL dialect you can't put a derived column in the where clause.

Instead use this where clause.

```
WHERE (amount1 + amount2) > 1000
```

Comment: Depending on the dialect? Which dialect allows such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use one of the variations in Andomar's answer.

What MySQL allows is this (don't use it, it's not standard and almost any other DBMS does NOT allow it):

```
SELECT (amount1 + amount2) AS totalamount 
  FROM Donation 
  HAVING totalamount > 1000 ;
```